# How To Make a Table for Controls (Excel VBA)

Tags: vba, excel

I hope you are enjoying your weekend!

I am here to ask if there is a way to initialize a table or list layout inside of  the frame of a userform. And, if this is possible, whether or not I can place controls (text boxes and labels) into the cells instead of strings of text.

Thank you in advance for your answers/comments.

*Edit: Follow up question. Assuming the above is possible in Excel VBA, can I also set the table (only one column) or list to have its dimensions based on the control's width and height?

Comment: When you talk about "table in a user form", are you talking about embedding an actual spreadsheet?

Comment: No not exactly. I meant a table control that can contain other objects like textboxes and labels.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can embed a Microsoft Office Spreadsheet.  Go to tool box additional controls.

[image]

You can access ot just like you do an Excel WorkSheet.

> Spreadsheet1.Range("A1")
>   You can also use Private WithEvents to hook it's events.  Here I did it in the Userform, however, I could have do it from a class module if I wanted.
>
> Private WithEvents MySpreadsheet1 As OWC11.Spreadsheet

Option Explicit
Private WithEvents MySpreadsheet1 As OWC11.Spreadsheet

Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    Set MySpreadsheet1 = Spreadsheet1
End Sub

Private Sub MySpreadsheet1_BeforeContextMenu(ByVal x As Long, ByVal y As Long, ByVal Menu As OWC11.ByRef, ByVal Cancel As OWC11.ByRef)

End Sub

Private Sub Spreadsheet1_BeforeContextMenu(ByVal x As Long, ByVal y As Long, ByVal Menu As OWC11.ByRef, ByVal Cancel As OWC11.ByRef)

End Sub
[image]
[image]
It's not fully featured but you can do alot with it.
[How To Use the Spreadsheet Web Component with Visual Basic](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/235883)
 You can hide the columns and rows, but it's too slow to be practical.

```
Spreadsheet1.Columns("E:ZZZ").EntireColumn.Hidden = True
Spreadsheet1.Rows("10:262144").EntireRow.Hidden = True
```